# Jquery Ajax "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've run into a problem with my AJAX call.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/Admin/changeStudentPhoto/",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    file: file1,
    filename: filename1,
    studentID: studentID1,
    x: x1,
    y: y1,
    w: w1,
    h: h1
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //do Stuff
  },
  error: function() {}
});
```

It sends the request to this controller:

```
public JsonResult changeStudentPhoto(string file, string filename, int studentID, double x, double y, double w, double h) { 
  // More Stuff 
}
```

The thing is that by applying a breakpoint on the call I can see that the parameters are properly set, I get an error 500 from the controller that includes an error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'h' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method

The specific parameter does not really matter, before `h` it was the `studentID`.

I usually place data directly in the URL but this time I need to also pass a base64 string so I can't place it in a URL.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added pics for clarification

[image: debugger]

[image: error]

Comment: Does the `h1` variable in your JS contain a value? Where is the error being raised from? I assume it's not the default model binder, as your breakpoint wouldn't even be hit (assuming it's in the controller action).

Comment: Also note that you can still send a base64 string in a GET request, although you're more tightly limited by request size. The HTTP request verb should have no bearing on the outcome, though.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint in the browser debugger, on the ajax call to see if the call's data contained the correct values. It did but the problem persisted. I then added "1" to the js variables to differentiate them from the controller's arguments (Just in case).

Comment: @MrNutbutters when you say, you see values when breakpoint is hit, did you mean in browser or C# Controller breakpoint? could you post the sample API call as well

Comment: In that case it means that your request is being sent absolutely fine by the JS logic. As such you need to debug the server side C#. Check what the actual response is from the request in dev tool and place a breakpoint in the action to step through that. Given this information, we need to see a more complete example of the C# as it's the cause of the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It won't get inside the action though. The action itself raises an error 500 int the console. Inside it is says the value for h is null. Before the ajax posts the value for h is a proper decimal number to be recieved by a double. The thing is that since the problem arises after the ajax is sent and the controller sees h as a null value.

Comment: Could you try adding Content-Type to your ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialy turned my data to a Json and created a model for it to bind.
That didn't really work though, the value for "h" would be shown as zero.

So i ended up rounding my numbers in js and passing them as ints. 
That solved the problem.

That is not a proper solution though since although in my case i can work with integers someone else might need to pass actual float numbers.